# Unable to load a pdf file that has been created

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I have saved and opened a PDF file on my view controller, and then I save the array of PDFs to the system data. I then pull my array from the data and use the string of the location in the new view controller. However when I attempt to load the file at said directory it fails to appear in the WebView, even though I was able to load it from the same directory on the first ViewController.

How can I get it to open after the app has been closed?

Here is how I save and open the PDF the first time:

```
    func generatePreview() {
        let A4paperSize = CGSize(width: 595, height: 842)
        let pdf = SimplePDF(pageSize: A4paperSize, pageMargin: 20.0)
        createFirstPage(x: pdf)
        pdf.beginNewPage()
        addAreas(x: pdf)
        //add disclamer and like dress the pdf up


        let pdfData = pdf.generatePDFdata()
        let resourceDocPath = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last! as URL
        let pdfNameFromUrl = "Survey-\(finalOverview.name).pdf"
        let actualPath = resourceDocPath.appendingPathComponent(pdfNameFromUrl)
        do {
            try pdfData.write(to: actualPath, options: .atomic)
            print("pdf successfully saved!")
        } catch {
            print("Pdf could not be saved")
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: actualPath)
        pdfPreview.load(request)
        let pdfObj = pdfArray(fileTitle: finalOverview.name, fileName: actualPath)
        //pdfView.GlobalVariable.myPDFs.append(pdfObj)
        savePDF(x: pdfObj)



    }
```

I made the mentioned changes but still no luck

Comment: You are using the wrong URL initializer. You need to use `URL(fileURLWithPath: path)` And make sure `path` object contains a valid file path.

Comment: Okay I have confirmed the URL to be valid as I was able to locate the file myself using the url i printed to the debug console

Comment: A URL created with just the file name `fileName` doesn't look like it will point to a file in the app documents directory

Comment: After changing that it still has an empty display

Comment: As I said you need to construct a new URL appending the file name (path component) to the document directory

Comment: Here is the URL:file:///Users/dylanrafferty/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4471DFA9-BEE3-4968-9302-21F4DA67A12C/data/Containers/Data/Application/5673C017-211C-4FEC-B4D8-7CEAC87708AB/Documents/Survey-test2.pdf

Comment: The issue is probably you are saving the whole string when you shouldnt. You should just save the file name and append it to the document url

Comment: Oh I see, how would I do that?

Comment: How can i change that?

Comment: You did it already when writing it to disk. actualPath is actually a file URL. use that url.

Comment: How can I change this line to save the URL directly instead of the String? Thank you so much!

Comment: self.fileName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "fileName") as? String ?? ""

Comment: Okay i was able to change that however the same thing is still occuring

Comment: @LeoDabus I have re written the code and it saves to that directory and confirms it saved, i can find it in finder, however when writing the same code to open it up after saving it fails to find the file. Do you think you would know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was when I was creating the string the second time, the optional was not wrapped. So when I unwrapped it the code worked as intended.